# Windows Batch selective deletion

Tags: batch-file

I would like to delete all subdirectories named `Debug Release x86 x64` from a particular location while excluding all `.git` subdirectories. I can easily do this in Linux (`find -type d -name Debug -and -not .git -delete` or something along those lines).

What did I do wrong here? `FINDSTR` with lowercase `debug release` keywords is meant to be an exclusion, I need a case sensitive search.

```
FOR /R C:\code /D %%I IN (DIR /S /B Debug Release x86 x64 ^| FINDSTR /V \. ^| FINDSTR /V debug ^| FINDSTR /V release) DO ECHO %%I
```

Comment: No black magic at all. You are not using the `FOR` command correctly. To parse the output of a command you need to use `FOR /F` and enclose the command in single quotes.

Comment: Do you want not to remove `Debug Release x86 x64` if found in a `.git` subfolder or in a subfolder of it if I understood correctly? You may check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you just want to just recursively delete a folder that starts with `debug` in a specific path?:

```
@cd /d "C:\code"
@for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s /ad "debug*"') do @echo @rmdir /S/Q "%%~fi"
```

just remove `@echo` once you are happy with the results. If I misunderstood your question, then please let me know, but that is what you pretty much shown with your linux find string.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

pushd "dir_with_subfolders"
for /F "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /S /B /AD "Debug Release x86 x64"') do (
    set "loc=%%~fA"
    if "!loc:\.git\=!" == "!loc!" (
        rd /s /q "%%~fA"
    )
)
popd
pause & exit /b
```

Comment: I replaced `rd /s /q` with `echo` to see if I get the correct dirs, but nothing happens, I don't even make it to the `popd`. `%errorlevel%` after batch execution is zero.

Comment: double-beep missed a `)`, which means, the `for` loop wasn't even executed. (I took the freedom to correct it) - Please try again.

Comment: Thank you @Stephan. Now the loop throws `File Not Found`. :(

Comment: might occur, when it tries to delete a subfolder, when it's parent folder got already deleted. If it nevertheless do what you want, you can suppress the error message with `2>nul`.

Comment: @Stephan I replaced the `rd /q /s` with `echo` to verify it first, yet I see no output. I am hesitant to run a delete command from the Internet which I don't understand.

Comment: That's wise `:)`. (You *do* have a backup?) See `rd /?` or [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/) for details. No output at all means there are no folders to delete. Be sure to be in the right folder and check all foldernames.